# How to auto-mount a prerequisite mountpoint for the one I'm mounting?

Tags: mount

I'm running Arch Linux and systemd.

In `/etc/fstab` I have something like this:

```
LABEL=XYZ       /mypath       vfat    noauto,[...]
/mypath/main    /newplace     none    bind,noauto    0 0
```

I currently have to mount `/newplace` with two commands:

```
mount /mypath
mount /newplace
```

I also have to `umount` both.

I need to simplify that to just one `mount` (or `umount`) command:

```
mount /newplace
```

I need to use the exact `mount` (and related `umount`) command shown immediately above because of an existing script. To clarify:

The single command `mount /newplace` should first mount `/mypath`, then mount `/newplace` and `/mypath` should remain mounted.

The command `umount /newplace` should first umount `/newplace` and then **also** umount `/mypath`.

I can change `/etc/fstab` and some other details of my device. But I cannot change the script that calls `mount /newplace`. I also cannot automount `/newplace` because it needs to usually remain unmounted except when the script is run.

I have been reading about recursive bind mounts, shared, private, slave and other mount options, but I have not seen a way to achieve what I'm seeking.

Update: in response to comments, this is obviously not a recursive mount, so I called it a "prerequisite" mount. I hope the term is appropriate. I thought about the term "reverse recursive mount" but that seems very bad. I am taking "prerequisite" to mean something that must come before and that provides the continuing foundation for the requisite. Generally, the prerequisite cannot be forgotten or removed while continuing with the requisite.

In this case, `/mypath` (prerequisite) and `/newplace` (requisite) both remain mounted when `/newplace` is mounted, and they would both be unmounted (probably in reverse order of course) when calling `umount /newplace`.

The ideal solution will use either systemd, Python 3 or Xonsh. (A Bash script is also acceptable. I do not have zsh or other shells installed.)

Comment: Are you able to automount `/mypath`?

Comment: @KeithLyons: no, /mypath should not be automounted. If I **could** do that, it would solve the entire issue.

Comment: It's neither "prerequisite" nor "recursive". You can unmount `/mypath` immediately after having bind-mounted `/mypath/main` (that's what the script from the answer does, btw). `/mypath` doesn't have to stay mounted while `/newplace` is mounted, and ("of course") they don't have to be unmounted in reverse order.

Comment: @user499944: RE: `/mypath doesn't have to stay mounted while /newplace is mounted`. Yes, **my requirement** is that it has to stay mounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do want the "main" subdir of the FS at `LABEL=XYZ` to be mounted on `/newplace`, without particularly needing the whole FS to be mounted at `/mypath`, you could add a line like:

```
LABEL=XYZ /newplace subdir subdir=main,srctype=vfat,noauto,... 0 0
```

And create the `/sbin/mount.subdir` helper (called by `mount /newplace`, not meant to be called directly) as a script like:

```
#! /bin/zsh -p
(( EUID == 0 )) || exec sudo -- "$0" "$@"
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin

# mount -t subdir -o subdir=foo -o otheroption source /dest calls us
# as mount.subdir source /dest -o rw,subdir=foo,otheroption
dev=${1?} dest=${2?} opts=( ${(s[,])4?} )

# extract mandatory subdir option
(( i = $opts[(I)subdir=*] )) || exit
subdir=${opts[i]#*=}
opts[i]=()

# extract optional srctype option
if (( i = $opts[(I)srctype=*] )); then
  type=(-t "$opts[i]")
  opts[i]=()
else
  type=()
fi

tmpdir=$(mktemp -d) || exit

mounted()true
if
  mount "$type[@]" -o "${(j[,])opts}" -- "$dev" "$tmpdir"
then
  mount --bind -- "$tmpdir/$subdir" "$dest" || mounted()false
  umount -- "$tmpdir"
fi && rmdir -- "$tmpdir" && mounted
```

Which mounts the whole FS in a tmpdir, bind-mounts the subdir into the destination and then unmounts and removes the tmpdir.

---

If, as clarified in your later edit, you do want both `/newplace` and `/mypath` to be mounted and `/mypath` is not just some intermediary step for the end goal of having a subdir of the FS mounted in `/myplace`, you can take a similar approach, and that becomes easier as you just need the helper to mount the prerequisite FS(s) instead:

```
LABEL=XYZ /mypath vfat noauto,[...]
/myplace/main /newplace prereq prereq=/myplace,noauto,... 0 0
```

And create the `/sbin/mount.prereq` helper as a script like:

```
#! /bin/zsh -p
(( EUID == 0 )) || exec sudo -- "$0" "$@"
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin

src=${1?} dst=${2?} opts=( ${(s[,])4?} )

# extract prereq options
for prereq in ${(M)opts:#prereq=*}; do
  prereq=${prereq#*=}
  mountpoint -q -- $prereq ||
    mount -- $prereq ||
    exit
done
opts=(${opts:#prereq=*})

exec mount --bind -o "${(j[,])opts}" -- "$src" "$dst"
```

Note that `/mypath` is not automatically unmounted after `/newplace` is unmounted.

The same with POSIX shell syntax (so should even work in `bash`) could look like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
[ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ] || exec sudo -- "$0" "$@"
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin

src="${1?}" dst="${2?}"

set -o noglob
IFS=,
set -- ${4?}

# extract prereq options
for opt do
  case $opt in
    (prereq=*)
      prereq=${opt#*=}
      mountpoint -q -- "$prereq" ||
        mount -- "$prereq" ||
        exit
      ;;
    (*)
      set -- "$@" "$opt"
  esac
  shift
done
opts="$*"

exec mount --bind -o "$opts" -- "$src" "$dst"
```

(untested).

If you can't *edit* your script, you could possibly instrument it. For instance, if it's written in `bash`, call it as:

```
bash -c '
  mount() {
    if [[ $1 = "/newplace" ]]; then
      command mount /mypath || return
    fi
    command mount "$@"
  }
  export -f mount
  exec "$0" "$@"' your-script its args
```

Or if it's written in `zsh`, add to `~/.zshenv` (or `/some/dir/.zshenv` and set `ZDOTDIR=/some/dir` for that script):

```
if [[ $ZSH_SCRIPT:P = /path/to/your-script ]]; then
  mount() {
    if [[ $1 = /newplace ]]; then
      command mount /mypath || return
    fi
    command mount "$@"
  }
fi
```

Or for any shell, add a `mount` script in `/some/dir` that does the same:

```
#! /bin/sh -
if [ "$1" = /newplace ]; then
  /bin/mount /mypath || exit
fi
exec /bin/mount "$@"
```

And call your script as:

```
PATH="/some/dir:$PATH" your-script its args
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was hoping for a **much** simpler solution. Maybe there is no solution like that...

Comment: @MountainX: Your comment suggests that you should edit your question to define what exactly you mean by `much simpler`. Does it mean an acceptable answer contains **no scripts**... or perhaps scripts with no more than 6 lines, etc? I thought your question was interesting & had begun fiddling around with a `systemd` solution - but perhaps that's not simple enough??

Comment: @Seamus - I will attempt to clarify my question. However, I can say that a systemd solution would be very interesting. I don't see why that would not meet my needs. Other approaches would be OK too, so I probably need to think more deeply about how to clarify my question.

Comment: @MountainX: Here are [some ideas](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=mount+a+drive+using+systemd) that may help you get started w/ a `systemd` solution. IIRC, `systemd` actually mounts drives by reading `/etc/fstab`, but it doesn't mount them in a predictable order ***unless*** it is coaxed to do so. This tutorial may be useful fpr learning **how** to create your `/etc/fstab` entries such that `systemd` mounts them in the desired order. N.B. there may be *distro-dependent* differences that require adjustments. `Arch` has excellent docs, so check there first.

Comment: @Seamus OK, following up. My main issue with this answer is that I do not want to unmount `/mypath`. I am taking prerequisite to mean something that must come before and that provides the continuing foundation for what follows it. The  prerequisite cannot be "forgotten" or removed.

Comment: @Seamus - I will investigate the systemd-mount approach. I assume that could work...

Comment: @MountainX: Would probably be much better to revise your question instead of addressing in the comments.

Comment: @MountainX, see edit.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - will any parts of the helper script need to change to be compatible with GNU bash, version 5+ ? Thank you.

Comment: @MountainX, yes, that script uses zsh for it own specific features. In a sh/bash script, you'd wrap that code inbetween `zsh << 'EOF'` and `EOF` for instance or add `[ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] || exec zsh - "$0" "$@"` though it'd be a bit silly.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I don't really understand your point, but it sounds like any device that runs this script needs to have zsh installed. None of my devices currently have it installed.

Comment: Could not get it to work, so tried running it directly like this: `/etc/fstab:  
LABEL=XYZ    /mypath    vfat  noauto,rw,relatime,[...] 0 0
/mypath/main /newplace  prereq prereq=/mypath,noauto   0 0
  
# /sbin/mount.prereq /mypath/main /newplace /mypath noauto`. Output:  
mount: /newplace: special device /mypath/main does not exist.

Comment: Since I have never used zsh, I can't debug it easily. I edited question to specify that I am seeking a solution that uses systemd, Python 3, Xonsh or bash.

Comment: @MountainX, `/mount.prereq` is not meant to be called directly, it's meant to be called as a helper my `mount /newplace` (which will call it as `/sbin/mount.prereq /mypath/main /newplace -o rw,prereq=/mypath` (hence the looking for options in `$4`, not `$3`)). To add debugging, insert a `set -o xtrace` at the top of the file like in any POSIX shell.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I'm slowly digesting this answer. Now that I understand it better, I see its excellence. I am going to try to alter my approach and use your first answer. However, I need it in Python, Xonsh or bash. If you (or anyone) wants to provide an alternative implementation in one of those languages, I'll accept that answer. I'll also accept a systemd solution, although this concept is really interesting and I now see it is quite good. Sorry it took me a while to catch on.